# Redshift Spectrum: Automatically partition tables by date/folder

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

We currently generate a daily CSV export that we upload to an S3 bucket, into the following structure:

```
<report-name>
|--reportDate-<date-stamp>
    |-- part0.csv.gz
    |-- part1.csv.gz
```

We want to be able to run reports partitioned by daily export.

According to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html) page, you can partition data in Redshift Spectrum by a key which is based on the source S3 folder where your Spectrum table sources its data. However, from the example, it looks like you need an `ALTER` statement for each partition:

```
alter table spectrum.sales_part
add partition(saledate='2008-01-01') 
location 's3://bucket/tickit/spectrum/sales_partition/saledate=2008-01/';

alter table spectrum.sales_part
add partition(saledate='2008-02-01') 
location 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/spectrum/sales_partition/saledate=2008-02/';
```

Is there any way to set the table up so that data is automatically partitioned by the folder it comes from, or do we need a daily job to `ALTER` the table to add that day's partition?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

At max 20000 partitions can be created per table. You can create a one-time script to add the partitions (at max 20k) for all the future s3 partition folders.

For eg.

If folder s3://bucket/ticket/spectrum/sales_partition/saledate=2017-12/ doesn't exist, you can even add partition for that.

```
alter table spectrum.sales_part
add partition(saledate='2017-12-01') 
location 's3://bucket/tickit/spectrum/sales_partition/saledate=2017-12/';
```

**Solution 2:**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/data-lake-ingestion-automatically-partition-hive-external-tables-with-aws/

Comment: Thats perfect, I have no idea why I didn't think of that, thank you

Comment: The docs for this also says "You can add multiple partitions ... if you use the AWS Glue catalog, you can add up to 100 partitions in a single statement" just by repeating the 2nd and 3rd lines in your example for each partition. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html#c-spectrum-external-tables-partitioning

Comment: I can't find any info on maximum number of partitions in AWS docs. Could you link? 

Update: I created 20001 partitions for a table without any problems. Maybe the 20k limit is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Another precise way to go about it:
Create a Lambda job that is triggered on the ObjectCreated notification from the S3 bucket, and run the SQL to add the partition:

alter table tblname ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (partition clause) localtion s3://mybucket/localtion